# Angular application client side caching

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, caching, express

## The problem

We are using [Angular.js](http://www.angularjs.org) for our front-end application that is served from an [Express](http://expressjs.com/) server.

**Some of our users are experiencing random issues with the application, but when they clear their browser's cache, the problem is resolved.**

We also notice that when we push a new version of our application online, we have to *hard refresh* before we can see the new changes.

**How can we make sure that when we push a new version of the application, that all the users see the new updated version?**

## Technical details

The express code we use in order to serve the Angular App:

```
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var schema = req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"];

    // --- Do nothing if schema is already https
    if (schema === "https")
        return next();

    // --- Redirect to https
    res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=3600");
   return next();
});

app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist"));

//prerender is used for SEO
app.use(prerender);
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));

//HTML5 mode
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
   response.sendfile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

As you can see, we use a middleware to set the Cache-Control max-age to 1hour. When we use curl to check the headers we get the following (correct Cache-Control value).

[image: screenshot of the curl command]

However, when we check the response header in Chrome, the Cache-Control max-age is set to one week.

[image: chrome header]

Also very important, we use [Grunt-rev](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev) so that every time we deploy the application, the CSS and JS file(s) have a different unique string prepended to their name. (As a result this will also changes the index.html page).

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to handle caching from gzippo!

What is happening in your code is that your custom middleware is going to write `Cache-Control` header but after gzippo handled the request, it is going to re-write `Cache-Control` header and set it to 1 week (the default according to the [doc](https://github.com/tomgco/gzippo)). Your middleware has been "ignored".

**What you need to do is**

1. Remove the custom middleware that injects `Cache-Control` header.
2. Update gzippo call like the following

   ```
   app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist", {
     clientMaxAge: 3600 * 1000 // 1 hour, it seems gzippo takes milliseconds, not seconds
   }));
   ```

And you're done :)

For other information you can checkout the other options the [gzippo documentation](https://github.com/tomgco/gzippo)

Hope that helps, Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!